# Permission error when attempting to open a .bat file written to by the same code in python

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

This is my code

```
import webbrowser
import os
import time
import sys
stopexpexe = open('C:\\Games\\windowsexplorerstop.bat', 'w')
stopexpexe.write('taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe')
stopexpexe.close
startexpexe = open('C:\\Games\\windowsexplorerrestart.bat', 'w')
startexpexe.write('start explorer.exe')
startexpexe.close
os.startfile('C:\\Games\\windowsexplorerstop.bat')
time.sleep(218)
os.startfile('C:\\Games\\windowsexplorerrestart.bat')
```

The Error I get is as following: "PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Games\windowsexplorerstop.bat'"

I need help in figuring out why this is happening, and how to fix it.

I am running on python 3.4.3. I am a very new coder, and might not understand more complicated more detailed posts, so please explain as much as possible. I know I might not be following a sort of "style" of code at this point, but I am self taught up to this point, so please bear with me. I will try to assist in any further problems, thanks.
- Scott Likely

Answer (score 3):

You aren't closing the files. `stopexpexe.close` should be `stopexpexe.close()`, and similarly for `startexpexe.close`